# After submission of form I want to redirect it to another page

Tags: php, wordpress

Code is here, but this is a plugin called newsletter.
I created custom form and after submission it should redirect to my `thanks.php` page.

```
<div class="tnp tnp-subscription">
<form method="post" action="https://mysite/thanks.php/" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)">

<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-profile"><label>Firma</label><input class="tnp-profile tnp-profile-1" type="text" required name="np1"></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-firstname"><label>Vorname</label><input class="tnp-firstname" type="text" name="nn" required></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-lastname"><label>Nachname</label><input class="tnp-lastname" type="text" name="ns" required></div>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email"><label>E-Mail</label><input class="tnp-email" type="email" name="ne" required></div>
   <p class="datenschutz">
 <input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNews" name="subscribe" value="newsletter" required>Ich habe die <a href="https://dev.textilrammelkamp.de/datenschutzbelehrung/" target="_top">Datenschutzhinweise</a> gelesen und erkläre mich der Verwendung meiner Daten gemäß den Datenschutzhinweisen einverstanden.</p>  </br>
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-button"><input class="tnp-submit" type="submit" value="Jetzt Anmelden">
</div>
```

[SCREEN SHOT OF WORDPRESS OLUGIN NEWSLETTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIqlk.png)

Comment: Hi! First of all: you need to do a [little more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), since this question has been answered thousands of times right now. Try searching for "wordpress redirect form" or "php redirect form" and there should be plenty of tutorials and answers.

Comment: sorry for that German language look at screen shot stack overflow change it from html php code to thats german

Comment: as per your action attribute, it will redirect to thankyou page, what else you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a function for java script redirect in functions.php and call when ever you want like this

```
function redirect($url){
    $string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $string .= 'window.location = "' . $url . '"';
    $string .= '</script>';
    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: this is a basic redirect, please post the answer related to newsletter plugin and how to redirect it after successful submit

Comment: I am noot understand this form is custom form please help me guys